# Ground/Earth connection missing on power strip?

Tags: ac, strip

I purchased a power strip with no cable from the hardware store, so that I could wire it up myself with some spare cable that I had lying around.

When I opened the power strip, I noticed that it does not have a connector for the ground (earth) wire.

[image: See live and neutral are connected through to the strip through a button]

Does this mean that if I want to have the ground connection work I have to solder the earth wire to the center piece of metal? Is this common for power strips to not have the earth connected but have the conductors on the plugs for it?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Note: I live in Europe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Earth terminal.*

It seems to be missing a screw.

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen it, it seems a bit far from where you insert the cable. Thank you!

Comment: Its somewhat of a "best practice" to have the ground wire longer than the other wires.  That way, if the cable gets pulled out, the last thing to disconnect is the safety ground.